# barcode App does not work on windows, an empty image is made, work fine in pycharm and for qrcode

Tags: windows, barcode

Bonjour
Here is my problem:
I made a tkinter App to transform entries (letters or numbers) in barcode or Qrcode... very simple thing...
The program function like a charm when I run it in pycharm but when I get the final App for Windows, only the Qrcode part works
I use PytoExe

Here is the part that create the barcode

```
import qrcode

def creer_barrecode():
number = entryMonUrl.get().strip()
desktop_path = str(Path.home() / "Desktop")
fila = desktop_path + '/bar_code.png'

if number:

    # my_code = EAN13(number, writer=ImageWriter())
    # my_code.save(fila)

    with open(fila, 'wb') as f:
        Code128(number, writer=ImageWriter()).write(f)
```

When I check the folder, only an empty image is there (0 octet) with the correct name
Thank you for your help
I tried EAN and Code128 but same things

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Ok,
no barcode is made with the App I got with PyExe
It is working when I run it in Pycharm

when I try to convert a number or letters in a barcode using the function def(), I have no result, only an empty image is create 
What do I do wrong?

Comment: question belongs in the "question" area at top of this page, not in comments ... added it for you